# jquery error displaying text of div on another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my personal project I am trying to make hover over function of image which has a div labeled as text to display on the #showHere div, which I thought i implemented correctly, but nothing is coming out and it is hard to debug it without anything showing

html

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content-left">
        <div id="showHere"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="content-right">

        <div class="item">
            <img src="guns/Rusty.png" />
            <div class="text"> rusty </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
    .container{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    }


#content{

overflow: auto;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
}

#content-left{
color: #FFFFFF;
float:left;
background-color:#333333;
width: 25%;
height = 300px;
width = 50px;
}

#content-right{
color: #FFFFFF;
float:right;
background-color:#666666;
width: 75%;
height = 300px;
width = 50px;
}
.text{
display: none;
}

#showHere{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Jquery/javascript

```
$(".item").hover(function () {
    "use strict";
    var data = $(this).find(".text").html();
    $("#showHere").hide().stop().html(data).fadeIn();
}, function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#showHere").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: `$("item").hover(function () {` missing `.` for class should be `$(".item").hover(function () {`

Comment: mesed up on the copy and pasted my bad.

Comment: when i create a sample snippet it is working ok what do you expect?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
[your code]
})

Comment: @guaradio for me the text didnt show at all do you want a picture of the website?

Comment: @HernánDanielGarau should I put the entire jquery function in there and what does it do?

Comment: if you´ve a code jquery before html, class and id are undefined. so, you say run your code when load entery page.... sorry for my english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/hjuob3fL/) if you make sure it execute after [DOM is ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Also you have few styles like`height=50px` in css which should be `height:50px`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".item").hover(function() {
    "use strict";
    var data = $(this).find(".text").html();
    $("#showHere").hide().stop().html(data).fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    "use strict";
    $("#showHere").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#content-left {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
}

#content-right {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 75%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}

#showHere {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="content-left">
    <div id="showHere"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="content-right">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="guns/Rusty.png" />
      <div class="text">rusty</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does DOM ready mean I am still a beginner at javascript despite knowing the functions

Comment: @chowster It mean all the elements have been created. If your scripts runs before elements are available then it won't work. It's better explained in the article I linked

Comment: wrapping the functions in document.ready or your shorthand way makes sure if its ready, but is this necessary for all jquery functions?

Comment: @chowster Ideally ALL of your javascript - jquery code that manipulates DOM should be in a single DOM ready wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Your forgot the `.` selector for `item`

Try with:

```
$(".item").hover(function () {
    "use strict";
    var data = $(this).find(".text").html();
    $("#showHere").hide().stop().html(data).fadeIn();
}, function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#showHere").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Sorry I posted it was a copy and paste error on the other comment, thanks though